# Word 2010 forms: applying "data-filled-in" style to Plain Text Content Control

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, styles, forms

[image]

*Figure 1. Field in Normal style.*

- I have created a form with pretty placeholder prompts (boxes added for demonstration) in faint colour in the Plain Text Content Controls. So far, so good.
- When the user types over the prompt the text style changes to normal. That's good too. The prompts are faint - the filled in data is normal.
- The "customer" wants the entered data in boxes (bordered). The "obvious" solution is to create a character style with border turned on and apply it to the Plain Text Content Control.
- The problem is that if I modify a style and apply it to the Plain Text Content Control then it always shows up in that style and the user never sees the *Placeholder* style.

Does anyone know how to apply a "data-filled-in" style to accompany the *Placeholder* style?

Answer (score 0):

After some web trawling I have determined that it is not possible with the Plain Text Content Control but is possible with the Rich Text Content Control.

Tip: Set the *Placeholder* style to something discrete (light blue, italics) and create a style for the "filled-in" text.

[image]

*Figure 1. Setting "filled-in" Rich Text Content Control" properties.*

- On Developer ribbon, you need to enter *Design mode*.
- Select the control to be formatted.
- Hit properties on the Developer ribbon.
- Enable *Use a style to format contents*.
- Select the style to use.